# SQLite optimization: simultaneous search for lower and upper bounds

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

For a long running algorithm based on SQLite3, I have a simple but huge table defined like that:

```
CREATE TABLE T(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, V INTEGER);
```

The inner loop of the algorithm will need to find, given some integer `N`, the biggest `ID` that is less or equal to `N`, the value `V` associated to it, as well as the smallest `ID` that is strictly bigger than `N`.

The following pair of requests does work:

```
SELECT ID, V FROM T WHERE ID <= ? ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID > ? LIMIT 1;
```

But I feel that it should be possible to merge those two requests into a single one. When SQLite has consulted the primary index to find the `ID` just smaller than `N` (first request), the next entry in the B-tree index is already the answer to the second request.

To give an order of magnitude, the table `T` has more than one billion of rows, and the inner requests will need to be executed more than 100 billions of times. Hence each microsecond counts. Of course I will use a fast SSD on a server with plenty of RAM. PostgreSQL could also be an option if it is quicker for that usage without taking more disk space.

Comment: isn't the second query missing  `ORDER BY ID` ? otherwise there is no guaranty that the selected id is the smallest possible value

Comment: @bwt In theory yes, but SQLite by default always enumerate in the order of the primary key, so the sort has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to my own question. While I didn't found yet a better SQL request as posted in the question, I made some preliminary speed measurements that moved slightly the perspective. Here are my observations:

1. There is a big difference in search or insert performance depending whether `ID` values are sequential or random order. In my application, `ID` will be *mostly* sequential, but with plenty of exceptions.
2. Executing the pair of SQL requests takes less time than the sum of each request taken separately. This is most visible with random order. This means that when the second SQL request runs, the B-Tree to access the next `ID` is always in cache memory and walking through the index is faster the second time.
3. The search and insertion times per request increase with the number of rows. In sequential order, the difference is small, but in random order the increase is substantial. Indexing a B-Tree is inherently O(log N), and in addition OS cache becomes less performant as the file size increases.

Here are my measurements on a fast server with SSD:

```
        | Insertion (µs)| Search (µs)
# rows  | sequ.  random | sequ.  random
10^5    | 0.60    0.9   |  1.1    1.3
10^6    | 0.64    3.1   |  1.2    2.5       
10^7    | 0.66    4.3   |  1.2    3.0
10^8    | 0.70    5.6   |  1.3    4.2
10^9    | 0.73          |  1.3    4.6
```

My conclusion is that SQLite internal logic doesn't seem to be the bottleneck for the foreseen algorithm. That bottleneck for huge tables is disk access, even on a fast SSD. I don't expect to have a better performance with another database engine, nor with a custom made B-Tree.